# Why am I getting Unexpected T_STRING with this wordpress function?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am piecing together a custom post type from the wordpress codex. However, anytime I add more than the first two arguments to the array, I get an error.

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_my_post_types' );

function create_my_post_types() {
    register_post_type( 'super_duper',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'Super Dupers' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'Super Duper' ),
                'add_new' => __( 'Add New' ),
                'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Super Duper' ),
                'edit' => __( 'Edit' ),
                'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Super Duper' ),
                'new_item' => __( 'New Super Duper' ),
                'view' => __( 'View Super Duper' ),
                'view_item' => __( 'View Super Duper' ),
                'search_items' => __( 'Search Super Dupers' ),
                'not_found' => __( 'No super dupers found' ),
                'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No super dupers found in Trash' ),
            ),
            'public' => true,
        )
    );
}
```

This is the error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /home/prayerpi/public_html/wp-content/themes/twentyeleven/functions.php on line 611
```

Line 611 is:

```
'labels' => array(
```

Here is the [link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type) to the register_post_type codex.

Comment: on `register_post_type( 'super_duper,`, you didn't close the quote

Comment: Nevermind, I saw that I was missing a ' on the line above.

Comment: Are you using an editor with syntax highlighting? it can minimize these mistakes. I should know, I do them a lot :D

Comment: The problem still happens after you fixed the quote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you intend to leave the single quote off of this?

```
register_post_type( 'super_duper,
```

Probably should be:

```
register_post_type( 'super_duper',
```

Answer (score 0):

your missing the ending '

```
register_post_type( 'super_duper,
```

change too:

```
 register_post_type( 'super_duper',
```